# Bug in libc? How to read dump file?

Tags: c++, c, boost, opencv, libc

I will try to ask my question in the best way I can:

I want to use example code (only one file called "main.cpp") from a camera manufacturer to read images from my camera under Ubuntu 11.10. If I use the example project, everything works fine and I receive image data. But if I add this "main.cpp" to my real project and compile, the application crashes.

It's very hard to determine the part which causes this error. But if I remove some code from me (which is compiled but definitly NOT used!), the program works as expected. I guess there is an error caused by another library I am linking against when my code is being compiled (e.g. Opencv or boost?). Im trying to figure out which part causes this behavior, but I would be glad if you guys could tell me in the mean time, if it's possible to extract useful information from this crash message which can be found [on this Gist](https://gist.github.com/2936131).

Is my libc damaged?

Comment: You might find it useful to paste the contents of the dump file into a Gist or something similar, rather than a file-sharing site.

Comment: Okay, here is the "dump.txt" without a file-sharing site: https://gist.github.com/2936131

Comment: Are you sure this code is not used? How about static destructors?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, so Im trying to hunt the problem down by removing sourcefile by sourcefile (if I remove all of "my" source files at once, it works). My guess it's another library which is used by the linker. Is the dump.txt i provided useful? Or totally useless?

Comment: It looks like your program crashes right before finishing. Is that right? One of the destructors seems to be called more than once. You won't get far without a debugger. Try running your program through valgrind or gdb.

Comment: Anonymous, try to start your program under valgrind.

Comment: valgrind -v --tool=memleak --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-origins=yes --track-fds=yes  ./your_executable

Answer (score 0):

> Bug in libc?

No.

> `*** glibc detected *** ./myProject: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x09c12660 ***`

This error means that your application corrupted heap in some way. It may have `free`ed the same pointer twice, or it may have written past the end of allocated buffer.

*The* tool to find such heap corruption bugs is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

The fact that the crash happens only when you link in extra code is likely just an accident -- the bug is probably present in the application even without the extra code, but has not yet manifested in a crash.

It's also possible, though less likely, that the extra code introduces the bug.

In either case, once you run the application under Valgrind, the error should become obvious.